# Quarkus & Mongo Kotlin Serialisation Issues

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, quarkus

I'm predominately a Spring Boot developer, I'm now swapping over to Quarkus to develop some quicker micro services.  I've setup an application to practise but can't mongo to play nicely with Kotlin, i Keep running into serialisation issues.
Code is here -> https://github.com/Sturge95/simulation/tree/main/map-service

I'm saving open maps data into the following data structure

```
@Serializable
@MongoEntity(collection = "map")
data class RoadMap(
    @SerialName("createdBy") var createdBy: Long,
    @SerialName("name") var name: String,
    @SerialName("roads") val roads: MutableList<Road>? = mutableListOf(),
) : PanacheMongoEntity()

@Serializable
@MongoEntity
data class Road(
    @SerialName("id") var id: Long,
    @SerialName("name") var name: String? = null,
    @SerialName("maxSpeed") var maxSpeed: String? = null,
    @SerialName("nodes") var nodes: List<Node>? = mutableListOf(),
    @SerialName("tags") var tags: Map<String, String>? = mutableMapOf()
)

@Serializable
@MongoEntity
data class Node(
    @SerialName("id") var id: Long,
    @SerialName("normalisedX") var normalisedX: Double,
    @SerialName("normalisedY") var normalisedY: Double,
    @SerialName("tags") var tags: Map<String, String>? = mutableMapOf()
)
```

Which is working fine and results in the following Json being added into my mongo DB

```
[
  {
    "_id": {"$oid": "64bd736ed50ce14bc85eaae0"},
    "createdBy": 1,
    "name": "testMap",
    "roads": [
      {
        "_id": 27693333,
        "maxSpeed": "30 mph",
        "name": "Reepham Road",
        "nodes": [
          {
            "_id": 304128015,
            "normalisedX": 0,
            "normalisedY": -0.00004540600822196832
          },
          {
            "_id": 1476181244,
            "normalisedX": 0.2011101243339129,
            "normalisedY": -0.00003081680359439185
          },
          {
            "_id": 304128013,
            "normalisedX": 0.2324600355239799,
            "normalisedY": -0.00002791542758700523,
            "tags": {
              "direction": "clockwise",
              "highway": "mini_roundabout"
            }
          },
          {
            "_id": 1476181238,
            "normalisedX": 0.2684280639431613,
            "normalisedY": -0.00002604041057685082
          },
          {
            "_id": 6772069708,
            "normalisedX": 0.4305506216696276,
            "normalisedY": -0.000014440302059930498
          },
        ],
        "tags": {
          "cycleway:both": "no",
          "highway": "tertiary",
          "highway_authority_ref": "C261",
          "lanes": "2",
          "maintenance": "salting",
          "maxspeed": "30 mph",
          "name": "Reepham Road",
          "salting:ref": "AYL068",
          "source:highway_authority_ref": "foi_request",
          "surface": "asphalt"
        }
      },
      {
        "_id": 42275938,
        "nodes": [
          {
            "_id": 527335285,
            "normalisedX": 0.6277975133214924,
            "normalisedY": -0.000056242609580749086
          },
          {
            "_id": 527335245,
            "normalisedX": 0.5509769094138159,
            "normalisedY": -0.00005395646547135862
          }
        ],
        "tags": {
          "highway": "service"
        }
      },
      {
        "_id": 42275946,
        "maxSpeed": "30 mph",
        "name": "Meredith Road",
        "nodes": [
          {
            "_id": 527335222,
            "normalisedX": 0.8147868561278628,
            "normalisedY": -0.00001720373758548093
          },
          {
            "_id": 527335224,
            "normalisedX": 0.8588587921846983,
            "normalisedY": -0.000016341820808019356
          },
          {
            "_id": 527335226,
            "normalisedX": 0.8933836589697722,
            "normalisedY": -0.00001552233745051373
          }
        ],
        "tags": {
          "cycleway:both": "no",
          "highway": "residential",
          "maintenance": "salting",
          "maxspeed": "30 mph",
          "name": "Meredith Road",
          "salting:ref": "AYL068",
          "sidewalk": "both",
          "surface": "asphalt"
        }
      },
      {
        "_id": 42275953,
        "maxSpeed": "20 mph",
        "name": "Arden Grove",
        "nodes": [
          {
            "_id": 527335271,
            "normalisedX": 0.7534413854351691,
            "normalisedY": -0.00004601864744613598
          },
          {
            "_id": 9682499019,
            "normalisedX": 0.7451598579040818,
            "normalisedY": -0.000046265294498072127,
            "tags": {
              "highway": "give_way"
            }
          },
          {
            "_id": 527335288,
            "normalisedX": 0.7230683836589353,
            "normalisedY": -0.00004692567234738203
          },
          {
            "_id": 527335289,
            "normalisedX": 0.6956927175843739,
            "normalisedY": -0.00004830477589658229
          },
          {
            "_id": 527335286,
            "normalisedX": 0.6682948490230718,
            "normalisedY": -0.00004994378955672427
          },
          {
            "_id": 527335287,
            "normalisedX": 0.6539964476020961,
            "normalisedY": -0.00005149793733721419
          }
        ],
        "tags": {
          "highway": "residential",
          "maxspeed": "20 mph",
          "name": "Arden Grove",
          "surface": "asphalt"
        }
      },
      {
        "_id": 42275958,
        "maxSpeed": "20 mph",
        "name": "Foxcotte Close",
        "nodes": [
          {
            "_id": 527335236,
            "normalisedX": 0.5311500888099177,
            "normalisedY": -0.00003872004016378303
          },
          {
            "_id": 527335240,
            "normalisedX": 0.5121003552397774,
            "normalisedY": -0.00004014421973409723
          }
        ],
        "tags": {
          "highway": "residential",
          "maxspeed": "20 mph",
          "name": "Foxcotte Close",
          "surface": "asphalt"
        }
      },
      {
        "_id": 42275975,
        "maxSpeed": "30 mph",
        "name": "Cottinghams Drive",
        "nodes": [
          {
            "_id": 527335230,
            "normalisedX": 0.6192051509768723,
            "normalisedY": -0
          },
          {
            "_id": 9682321620,
            "normalisedX": 0.6250444049733275,
            "normalisedY": -0.0000004481903240139725,
            "tags": {
              "highway": "give_way"
            }
          },
          {
            "_id": 527335209,
            "normalisedX": 0.6586145648312598,
            "normalisedY": -0.0000030339071176792973
          },
          {
            "_id": 527335212,
            "normalisedX": 0.7337921847246548,
            "normalisedY": -0.000008794109270993056
          },
          {
            "_id": 527335215,
            "normalisedX": 0.7736900532859587,
            "normalisedY": -0.000011682177204628757
          },
          {
            "_id": 527335206,
            "normalisedX": 0.7963143872113554,
            "normalisedY": -0.000013968237917030111
          },
          {
            "_id": 527335220,
            "normalisedX": 0.8088365896980488,
            "normalisedY": -0.00001590953663416455
          },
          {
            "_id": 527335222,
            "normalisedX": 0.8147868561278628,
            "normalisedY": -0.00001720373758548093
          }
        ],
        "tags": {
          "cycleway:both": "no",
          "highway": "residential",
          "maintenance": "salting",
          "maxspeed": "30 mph",
          "name": "Cottinghams Drive",
          "salting:ref": "AYL068",
          "surface": "asphalt"
        }
      },
      {
        "_id": 42275991,
        "maxSpeed": "20 mph",
        "name": "Foxcotte Close",
        "nodes": [
          {
            "_id": 527335251,
            "normalisedX": 0.7648978685612634,
            "normalisedY": -0.00003099979738798589
          },
          {
            "_id": 527335265,
            "normalisedX": 0.7369005328596859,
            "normalisedY": -0.000030307603622782024
          },
          {
            "_id": 527335238,
            "normalisedX": 0.5126776198934104,
            "normalisedY": -0.000037340948021022766
          }
        ],
        "tags": {
          "highway": "residential",
          "maxspeed": "20 mph",
          "name": "Foxcotte Close",
          "surface": "asphalt"
        }
      },
      {
        "_id": 42275992,
        "maxSpeed": "20 mph",
        "name": "Loxwood",
        "nodes": [
          {
            "_id": 527335234,
            "normalisedX": 0.7921847246891576,
            "normalisedY": -0.00002673525386747542
          },
          {
            "_id": 527335232,
            "normalisedX": 0.815985790408512,
            "normalisedY": -0.00002751496401077154
          },
          {
            "_id": 527335254,
            "normalisedX": 0.8529085257548843,
            "normalisedY": -0.000028894044459803096
          },
          {
            "_id": 527335380,
            "normalisedX": 0.9773534635879119,
            "normalisedY": -0.00003959258200163078
          },
          {
            "_id": 527335384,
            "normalisedX": 1,
            "normalisedY": -0.00003821083672011037
          }
        ],
        "tags": {
          "highway": "residential",
          "maxspeed": "20 mph",
          "name": "Loxwood",
          "sidewalk": "both",
          "surface": "asphalt"
        }
      },
      {
        "_id": 42276002,
        "nodes": [
          {
            "_id": 527335249,
            "normalisedX": 0.5634769094138178,
            "normalisedY": -0.00005201510301599034
          },
          {
            "_id": 527335245,
            "normalisedX": 0.5509769094138159,
            "normalisedY": -0.00005395646547135862
          },
          {
            "_id": 527335247,
            "normalisedX": 0.5343028419182825,
            "normalisedY": -0.00005662982237141346
          }
        ],
        "tags": {
          "highway": "service",
          "service": "parking_aisle"
        }
      },
      {
        "_id": 42655798,
        "maxSpeed": "20 mph",
        "name": "Cottinghams Drive",
        "nodes": [
          {
            "_id": 527335251,
            "normalisedX": 0.7648978685612634,
            "normalisedY": -0.00003099979738798589
          },
          {
            "_id": 527335274,
            "normalisedX": 0.7433170515097742,
            "normalisedY": -0.00003502036398600022
          },
          {
            "_id": 527335271,
            "normalisedX": 0.7534413854351691,
            "normalisedY": -0.00004601864744613598
          },
          {
            "_id": 527335297,
            "normalisedX": 0.7790630550621396,
            "normalisedY": -0.00004847716395600612
          },
          {
            "_id": 527335299,
            "normalisedX": 0.8317495559502375,
            "normalisedY": -0.000052574703062222666
          },
          {
            "_id": 527335291,
            "normalisedX": 0.8783747779751132,
            "normalisedY": -0.000055934961154710675
          }
        ],
        "tags": {
          "highway": "residential",
          "maxspeed": "20 mph",
          "name": "Cottinghams Drive",
          "surface": "asphalt"
        }
      },
      {
        "_id": 54835279,
        "maxSpeed": "30 mph",
        "name": "Cottinghams Drive",
        "nodes": [
          {
            "_id": 527335222,
            "normalisedX": 0.8147868561278628,
            "normalisedY": -0.00001720373758548093
          }
        ],
        "tags": {
          "highway": "residential",
          "maxspeed": "30 mph",
          "name": "Cottinghams Drive",
          "surface": "asphalt"
        }
      },
      {
        "_id": 287706617,
        "maxSpeed": "20 mph",
        "name": "Arden Grove",
        "nodes": [
          {
            "_id": 527335287,
            "normalisedX": 0.6539964476020961,
            "normalisedY": -0.00005149793733721419
          },
          {
            "_id": 527335285,
            "normalisedX": 0.6277975133214924,
            "normalisedY": -0.000056242609580749086
          },
          {
            "_id": 2912780152,
            "normalisedX": 0.6067495559502534,
            "normalisedY": -0.000059838919652649714
          }
        ],
        "tags": {
          "highway": "residential",
          "maxspeed": "20 mph",
          "name": "Arden Grove",
          "parking:lane:left": "no_stopping",
          "surface": "asphalt"
        }
      },
      {
        "_id": 287706618,
        "maxSpeed": "20 mph",
        "name": "Cottinghams Drive",
        "nodes": [
          {
            "_id": 2912780150,
            "normalisedX": 0.7988232682060127,
            "normalisedY": -0.000025555081350112012
          }
        ],
        "tags": {
          "highway": "residential",
          "maxspeed": "20 mph",
          "name": "Cottinghams Drive",
          "surface": "asphalt"
        }
      },
      {
        "_id": 313844837,
        "nodes": [
          {
            "_id": 3198819172,
            "normalisedX": 0.5156305506216505,
            "normalisedY": -0.00000829817913769176
          },
          {
            "_id": 3198819057,
            "normalisedX": 0.39742451154527825,
            "normalisedY": -0.000001259706973709907
          }
        ],
        "tags": {
          "highway": "service"
        }
      },
      {
        "_id": 721925883,
        "nodes": [
          {
            "_id": 6772069708,
            "normalisedX": 0.4305506216696276,
            "normalisedY": -0.000014440302059930498
          }
        ],
        "tags": {
          "highway": "service"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The issue then comes when I try and load RoadMap(s) from Mongo, i get the following json response

```
[
    {
        "createdBy": 1,
        "name": "testMap",
        "roads": null
    }
]
```

I'm using Kotlin x for serialisation and have the Kotlin No-Arg set up for the MongoEntity annotation.

My Pom Setup is as follows

```
     <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-kotlin</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-mongodb-panache-kotlin</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive-kotlin-serialization</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-container-image-docker</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
      <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlinx</groupId>
      <artifactId>kotlinx-serialization-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
      <artifactId>bson-kotlinx</artifactId>
      <version>4.10.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>kotlin-extensions</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkiverse.mockk</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5-mockk</artifactId>
      <version>LATEST</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
      <artifactId>mongodb</artifactId>
      <version>${test.containers.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>build</goal>
              <goal>generate-code</goal>
              <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-parameters</arg>
          </compilerArgs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
            <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <systemPropertyVariables>
                <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner</native.image.path>
                <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
              </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>compile</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>test-compile</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>test-compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-serialization</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-noarg</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <configuration>
          <javaParameters>true</javaParameters>
          <jvmTarget>17</jvmTarget>
          <compilerPlugins>
            <plugin>all-open</plugin>
            <plugin>kotlinx-serialization</plugin>
            <plugin>no-arg</plugin>
          </compilerPlugins>
          <pluginOptions>
            <option>all-open:annotation=jakarta.ws.rs.Path</option>
            <option>all-open:annotation=jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped</option>
            <option>all-open:annotation=io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTest</option>
            <option>all-open:annotation=io.quarkus.mongodb.panache.common.MongoEntity</option>
            <option>no-arg:annotation=io.quarkus.mongodb.panache.common.MongoEntity</option>
          </pluginOptions>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>native</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>native</name>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <skipITs>false</skipITs>
        <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction, Ideally I want roads to not be nullable, but in doing this i then get the error (se below). Which makes me think it has something to do with serialising the road entity. Not sure what could be the solution though as I'm new to Quarkus and mongo

```
2023-07-23 19:45:19,698 ERROR [io.qua.ver.htt.run.QuarkusErrorHandler] (executor-thread-1) HTTP Request to /v1/map failed, error id: e8c76425-4236-4f87-b5e2-8fe686ad0d61-1: java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlinx.serialization.internal.CollectionSerializer.collectionSize, parameter <this>
        at kotlinx.serialization.internal.CollectionSerializer.collectionSize(CollectionSerializers.kt)
        at kotlinx.serialization.internal.CollectionSerializer.collectionSize(CollectionSerializers.kt:205)
        at kotlinx.serialization.internal.CollectionLikeSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializers.kt:65)
        at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.StreamingJsonEncoder.encodeSerializableValue(StreamingJsonEncoder.kt:228)
        at kotlinx.serialization.encoding.AbstractEncoder.encodeSerializableElement(AbstractEncoder.kt:80)
        at shane.sturgeon.model.entity.RoadMap.write$Self(RoadMap.kt:8)
        at shane.sturgeon.model.entity.RoadMap$$serializer.serialize(RoadMap.kt:8)
        at shane.sturgeon.model.entity.RoadMap$$serializer.serialize(RoadMap.kt:8)
        at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.StreamingJsonEncoder.encodeSerializableValue(StreamingJsonEncoder.kt:228)
        at kotlinx.serialization.encoding.AbstractEncoder.encodeSerializableElement(AbstractEncoder.kt:80)
        at kotlinx.serialization.internal.CollectionLikeSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializers.kt:69)
        at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.StreamingJsonEncoder.encodeSerializableValue(StreamingJsonEncoder.kt:228)
        at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.JsonStreamsKt.encodeByWriter(JsonStreams.kt:28)
        at kotlinx.serialization.json.JvmStreamsKt.encodeToStream(JvmStreams.kt:25)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.kotlin.serialization.runtime.KotlinSerializationMessageBodyWriter.writeResponse(KotlinSerializationMessageBodyWriter.kt:45)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.core.ServerSerialisers.invokeWriter(ServerSerialisers.java:227)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.core.ServerSerialisers.invokeWriter(ServerSerialisers.java:195)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.core.serialization.FixedEntityWriter.write(FixedEntityWriter.java:28)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.ResponseWriterHandler.handle(ResponseWriterHandler.java:34)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.invokeHandler(QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.java:147)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.run(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:145)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:576)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2513)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1538)
        at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
        at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

--- Update

If i mark everything a var it works and displays fine, but I don't want all fields to be mutable

```
@Serializable
@MongoEntity(collection = "map")
data class RoadMap(
    @SerialName("createdBy") var createdBy: Long,
    @SerialName("name") var name: String,
    @SerialName("roads") var roads: MutableList<Road>? = mutableListOf(),
) : PanacheMongoEntity()

@Serializable
@MongoEntity(collection = "map")
data class Road(
    @SerialName("id") var id: Long,
    @SerialName("name") var name: String? = null,
    @SerialName("maxSpeed") var maxSpeed: String? = null,
    @SerialName("nodes") var nodes: List<Node>? = mutableListOf(),
    @SerialName("tags") var tags: Map<String, String>? = mutableMapOf()
)

@Serializable
@MongoEntity(collection = "map")
data class Node(
    @SerialName("id") var id: Long,
    @SerialName("normalisedX") var normalisedX: Double,
    @SerialName("normalisedY") var normalisedY: Double,
    @SerialName("tags") var tags: Map<String, String>? = mutableMapOf()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay after some digging I found the solution.
I could implement a custom Codec to create the object.

```
class RoadCoded : CollectibleCodec<RoadMap> { ... }
```

And Implement the CodecProvder to register the codec which Quarkus automatically picks ups.

```
class CustomCodecProvider : CodecProvider {
    override fun <T> get(clazz: Class<T>, registry: CodecRegistry): Codec<T>? {
        return if (clazz == RoadMap::class.java) {
            RoadCode() as Codec<T>
        } else null
    }
}
```

Source and documentation here -> https://quarkus.io/guides/mongodb#simplifying-mongodb-client-usage-using-bson-codec